# PIE.htc rounded corners are not working in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, css, css3pie

My code is here

http://jsfiddle.net/parag1111/s5RLb/

**PIE.htc is in CSS folder.**
I've also added JS of PIE and also added behaviour of PIE.htc.
Let me know what else can i do to make it work in IE8 and IE7.

I've used http://css3pie.com/

Comment: Did u check the path of the htc file ?

Answer (score 2):

Got the answer, I need to put full URL of PIE.htc, if its in local we need to give D:/project/PIE.htc ..

Answer (score 0):

It could be a server configuration issue.  Bundled in the PIE zip folder there is a `PIE.php` file, which is designed in the case that:

```
the web server is not configured to serve .htc files with the text/x-component
content-type, and cannot easily be configured to do so (as is the case with some
shared hosting providers)
```

Try uploading `PIE.php` to your server and then changing

```
behavior: url(PIE.htc);
```

to

```
behavior: url(PIE.php);
```